# Jointable with three columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to create the following mappings in JPA-2.0 using Hibernate 3.6 and MySQL 5.1:

```
Table "PIPE"
------------
pipe_id (PK)
============
pipe_name
pipe_modified_date
------------


Table "ALGO"
------------
algo_id (PK)
============
algo_name
------------
```

The table "Pipe" can store multiple algos (many-to-many between "Pipe" and "Algo"). It is important to store the order index of the list too. It should be also possible to store the same algo more than once.

How to model the appropriate jointable with a composite primary key consisting of three columns?

```
Table "PIPE_ALGO_JT"
---------------------
order_index (PK)
pipe_id (FK PK)
algo_id (FK PK)
=====================
---------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@OrderColumn` should do exactly what you want:

```
@Entity
public class Pipe {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PIPE_ALGO_JT")
    @OrderColumn(name = "order_index")
    private List<Aglo> algos;

    ...
}
```

Though in schema generated by Hibernate primary key would consist of `pipe_id` and `order_index` (since having `algo_id` in primary key is redundant in this case).

Comment: @bronogard: At the `Algo` side this order obviously doesn't make sense, so you simply do `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "algos")`.